# What's the translation of “road kilometres" in French?

Tags: traduction

I read on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Chaiyaphum&oldid=1015190532):

> Chaiyaphum is 337 road kilometres northeast of Bangkok.

What's the translation of “road kilometres" in French?

[Linguee](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=anglais&query=road+kilometres+) and  [translate.google.com](https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=fr&text=337%20road%20kilometres%20northeast%20of%20Bangkok%0A&op=translate) suggest  "kilomètres de route", however [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22kilom%C3%A8tres+de+route) yields almost no result for that phrase. Is there a better translation?

Comment: Il faut tout simplement supprimer *road* et, si vraiment nécessaire (les différences sont significatives entre les moyens terrestres) signifier le moyen de transport, « Chaiyaphum se trouve à 337 kilomètres [en voiture/en train/…] au nord-est de Bangkok.

Answer (score 1):

The expression ***km de route*** does exist in French and Google finds many occurences but *Chaiyaphum est à 337 km de route au nord-est de Bangkok* is not something I would expect to hear from a native French speaker. What would be more common is: ***Il y a 337 km de route pour aller de Bangkok à Chaiyaphum*** but it is difficult to place northeast in this sentence.

Here is what I can suggest:

> *Chaiyaphum se trouve au nord-est de Bangkok, **à 337 km par la route**.*

This is close to what I found [here](https://www.rome2rio.com/fr/s/Bangkok/Chaiyaphum):

> *La distance entre Bangkok et Chaiyaphum est de 282 km. **La distance par la route est de 337.5 km**.*

Answer (score 1):

"Kilomètres de route" is completely correct. As a native French speaker, I use it on a daily basis.

We tend to consider it the normal way to express a distance though, and so usually omit it. The opposite being "kilomètres à vol d'oiseau", is also frequently used.

Answer (score 1):

[Suggestion](https://qr.ae/pGN3yl) from [Gilles Thésée](https://www.quora.com/profile/Gilles-Th%C3%A9s%C3%A9e):

> “kilomètres par la route”, as opposed to “kilomètres à vol d’oiseau” (“as the crow flies”)

https://www.google.com/search?q=%22kilom%C3%A8tres+par+la+route%22 does return a few results (but not that many).